# ¿Tupla dentro de un diccionario - Python?

Tags: python, tuplas

Estoy teniendo un problema con tuplas dentro de diccionarios. Básicamente, lo que quiero hacer es que me imprima un valor que esta dentro de la tupla y no toda la tupla, y no consigo hacerlo.

Este es mi diccionario:

```
{3:('Tres', 'Three', 'Drei'), 5:('Cinco', 'Five', 'Fünf'),
1:('Uno', 'One', 'ein')}
```

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es pedir al usuario que ingrese un número, y que elija en que idioma quiere que le muestre el número, ingles, español o alemán. El problema es que al intentar imprimirlo, siempre me imprime toda la tupla.

Estoy intentando imprimir como si fuera un arreglo en C:
`diccionario[3][2]` y debería decir `'Drei'` pero me marca error.

```py
def agregarDicEle2(dic):
    numero=int(input("Ingrese numero:"))
    while(numero!=0):
        esp=input("Ingrese nombre en español:")
        eng=input("Ingrese nombre en ingles:")
        deu=input("Ingrese nombre en aleman:")
        dic[numero]={(esp,eng,deu)}
        numero=int(input("Ingrese numero:"))
    
    
def main():
    dic={}
    agregarDicEle2(dic)
    print(dic)
    num=int(input("Ingrese un número a traducir:"))
    idioma=input("Ingrese el idioma - eng / esp / deu :")
    if(dic.get(num,"Error.No existe en el diccionario")):
        if(dic.get(num)):
            if(idioma=="eng"):
                print(num,"en ingles es:",dic[num][1])
            if(idioma=="esp"):
                print(num,"en español es:",dic[num][0])
            if(idioma=="deu"):
                print(num,"en español es:",dic[num][2])
                
main()
```

He logrado una solución intermedia convirtiendo la tupla en lista y desde ahí sacar los elementos, pero es medio tramposo, quería saber si hay alguna forma mejor.

Comment: Te marca error: _¿qué error?_ Pulsa en [edit] y agrega los detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código

Comment: el problema que tienes es por que no tienes un *diccionario de tuplas*, sino un diccionario cuyo valor es un set con una tupla

Comment: prueba almacenándolo así `dic[numero]=(esp,eng,deu)`

Answer (score 1):

Hago esta respuesta solo para explicar algo curioso.

Tu error es al omento de almacenar el valor, pues haces

```py
def agregarDicEle2(dic):
    ...
        ....
        dic[numero]= {(esp,eng,deu)}
```

Aquí estas asignando a la clave, por ejemplo, `1` el valor de un `set` (no diccionario), tal que quedaria asi

```py
dic = {
  1:{
    ("esp","eng","deu")
  }
}
```

Como vez el valor no es la tupla sino un `set` y aquí explico. Las llaves `{}` no son únicas de la sintaxis de un diccionario, pues existe un tipo de dato llamado `set` y estos contienen elementos sin repetirse, sus elementos se almacenan de igual forma que una lista pero se declara con llaves `{}`. Por ejemplo

```
A = {1,2,3,4}
```

> Si colocas datos repetidos, al momento de imprimirlo o usarlo el `set` contendrá solo datos únicos.

Es muy parecido a una lista y a un diccionario, por lo que se *podría confundir*. El tipo de dato `set` se utiliza para guardar elementos sin repetición y se puede hacer las típicas operaciones de conjuntos como unión, intersección, etc. Cuando se quiere obtener datos no repetidos muchas veces se convierte a `set` con la función `set(dato)`, que seguramente has visto.

Tu error se soluciona simplemente eliminando las llaves `{}` de tal forma que solo se almacene como valor la tupla.

```py
def agregarDicEle2(dic):
    ...
        ....
        dic[numero]= (esp,eng,deu)
```

Recuerda que los diccionarios pueden guardar cualquier tipo de dato como valor, teniendo en cuenta su sintaxis `{key: value}`. La *llave* (*key*) debe ser un tipo de dato inmutable, mientras que su *valor* (*value*) puede ser tanto un dato mutable como inmutable.